# Javascript (Vanilla) element.checked = true/false does not work

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, checked

My HTML code :

```
<ul class="nav md-pills pills-default flex-column" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <input type="radio" name="q01" value="1" hidden checked>
        <a class="nav-link choice01 active" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-1" role="tab">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <input type="radio" name="q01" value="2" hidden>
        <a class="nav-link choice01" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-2" role="tab">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <input type="radio" name="q01" value="3" hidden>
        <a class="nav-link choice01" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-3" role="tab">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <input type="radio" name="q01" value="4" hidden>
        <a class="nav-link choice01" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-4" role="tab">4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My JS code :

```
const choices01 = document.getElementsByClassName("choice01");
const inputs01 = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=q01]");

for (let k=0; k<choices01.length; k++) {
    choices01[k].addEventListener("click", function(){
        inputs01[k].checked = true;
    });
}
```

I have several questions which each have an "a" element and the "choice[numberOfTheQuestion]" class.
For each of them, I have a hidden radio input that I would like to check when I click on the element "a".

However when I do a console.log(inputs01[k]) in the for and that I click then on one of the 4 choices, this one is displayed without the checked as if I had not clicked.

NB : inputs01[k] sends me back the correct element on which I clicked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.checked = true;` works, it just does not modify the html.

To verify that an element is well checked, you should not do `console.log(element)` (which will just return the element without the checked) but rather make a `console.log(element.checked)` and look in the console if we have true (checked) or false (not checked).

---

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `checked` property doesn't seem to work, but `setAttribute` does. Clicking below results in the `checked` property going from `false` to `true`, as you can see in the logs:

```js
const choices01 = document.getElementsByClassName("choice01");
const inputs01 = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=q01]");

for (let k = 0; k < choices01.length; k++) {
  choices01[k].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(inputs01[k].checked);
    inputs01[k].setAttribute('checked', true);
    console.log(inputs01[k].checked);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav md-pills pills-default flex-column" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <input type="radio" name="q01" value="1" checked hidden>
    <a class="nav-link choice01 active" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-1" role="tab">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <input type="radio" name="q01" value="2" hidden>
    <a class="nav-link choice01" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-2" role="tab">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <input type="radio" name="q01" value="3" hidden>
    <a class="nav-link choice01" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-3" role="tab">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <input type="radio" name="q01" value="4" hidden>
    <a class="nav-link choice01" data-toggle="tab" href="#answer1-4" role="tab">4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem with doing this is that it adds me "checked=true" but not checked and suddenly it does not uncheck which one is checked by default.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want from your question. You have set the hidden property for the inputs, so it will not show up, but it did change when you click the a tags.

If you want to show the radio button as checked when a particular a tag is clicked, you need to set the hidden property of that particular input to false.
https://jsfiddle.net/y718p9k3/3/

```
const choices01 = document.getElementsByClassName("choice01");
const inputs01 = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=q01]");

for (let k=0; k<choices01.length; k++) {
    choices01[k].addEventListener("click", function(){
        inputs01[k].checked = true;
        for (let j=0;j<inputs01.length;j++) {
            inputs01[j].hidden = true;
        }
        inputs01[k].hidden = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: No, my question is about checked radio inputs and not hidden ones.
The hidden is just there to hide it from the user but I don't touch it.